# get button value with ng-click or ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem with the angular,
I have a more than button with value 1 - 9, I would if I click the button 1.
value of input type="text" automatic be 1..

this example code :

```
<input type="text" class="tags" ng-model="data.tes">
<br>
<button value="1" class="phoneNumber" ng-model="data.tes">1</button>
```

any suggestion for me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
<button class="phoneNumber" ng-click="data.tes = 1">1</button>
```

For more than 1 button

in your controller

```
$scope.buttons = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

and in your markup

```
<button ng-repeat="button in buttons" ng-click="data.tes = button">{{button}}</button>
```

**EDIT**

You may want to declare your object in the controller as well

```
$scope.data = {};
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, so far it's work. But i have nine button with value 1 - 9. how to create multiple value input text ?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I mean, if I click button 1, 2 and 3. The value of the input text be 123.

Comment: simple, change your ng-click to - ng-click="data.tes = data.tes + '' + button"

Comment: note the '' in + '' + is two single quote to convert it to a string, I've updated the plnkr for you

Comment: hi Yang Li, may i ask ?

Comment: Yes? What would you like to ask

Comment: You can check this link [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28537574/how-to-create-backspace-for-mobile-apps") , I think it's still in the surrounding this topic

Comment: I was looking for a way to update a an scope attribute without writing a controller and a method for it. Thanks for this.

Comment: Very simple and nice explanation.